# Depencies are not installable

Tags: apt, gcc, g++

I am trying to install a program with the command:

```
~/Downloads$ sudo apt install  ./argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb
```

and I am getting the response (error) of:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'argos3_simulator:i386' instead of './argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 argos3_simulator:i386 : Depends: gcc:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
                         Depends: g++:i386 (>= 4.2) but it is not installable
                         Depends: cmake:i386 (>= 2.6) but it is not installable
                         Depends: freeglut3-dev:i386 (>= 2.6.0) but it is not installable
                         Depends: qt5-default:i386 (>= 5.5.1) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxi-dev:i386 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libxmu-dev:i386 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libfreeimage-dev:i386 (>= 3.15) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libfreeimageplus-dev:i386 (>= 3.15) but it is not installable
                         Depends: liblua5.2-dev:i386 but it is not installable
                         Depends: lua5.2:i386 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have used followed lots of forum advice such as; using synaptic and made sure gcc and g++ are installed and tried reinstalling them too.The rest I cannot find in synaptic. However I am still getting the error.

Any help is greatly appreciated, please note I am not an Ubuntu/Linux wizz! (this is probably obvious!)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: The feedback `selecting 'argos3_simulator:i386'` indicates that you seem to have tried to install argos3 before some other way, and apparently did not clean up afterward. 1) Make sure to clean up, and 2) Try passing the complete /path/home/to/file.deb instead of the shortcut "/."

Answer (score 1):

First off to install a deb file I use

```
sudo dpkg -i  some-file.deb
```

so in your case issue

```
sudo dpkg -i    ./argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb
```

however looks like that deb wants the 32 bit libraries not the normal 64 bit ones so give yourself that

```
dpkg --print-foreign-architectures  # show what you currently have

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386   # make your machine 32 bit savvy
```

Most importantly to jackup your machine so it becomes a developer box with a basic set of tools to compile code etc issue

```
sudo apt-get install  build-essential
```

now finally re-issue your original command

```
sudo dpkg -i    ./argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb
```

If its still showing similar errors just install them using (update with missing libraries in your error message) :  [then re-issue original command again]

```
sudo apt-get install libfreeimageplus-dev:i386
```

***UPDATE***  I battled using above approach, looks like the precompiled binary is using an obsolete library(s) so below will compile it from source (on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04)

https://github.com/ilpincy/argos3

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libfreeimage-dev libfreeimageplus-dev  qt5-default freeglut3-dev libxi-dev libxmu-dev liblua5.2-dev lua5.2 doxygen graphviz graphviz-dev asciidoc
```

download the source code, compile and install by issuing following :

```
git clone git@github.com:ilpincy/argos3.git


cd argos3
mkdir build_simulator
cd build_simulator
cmake ../src
make 
make doc
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

I can confirm above runs OK ... ignore

```
[WARNING] Error opening directory "/home/scott/src/github.com/ilpincy/argos3/build_simulator/plugins/simulator/physics_engines/physx/": No such file or directory
```

then just issue this to see help

```
argos3 --help
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log you post, it is installing `argos3_simulator:i386` in one of your repo (package source), not the deb file you want to install. Install `gdebi`and use:

```
$ sudo apt install gdebi
$ sudo gdebi ./argos3_simulator-3.0.0-i686-beta52.deb
```

Wish gdebi can help you complete the dependencies. But of coz, maybe your repos have problem as mentioned by Michael Haken.